# Wordpress menu item child

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on creating a custom menu for the WordPress project. I have cleaned up the markup for the menu using the following function `clean_custom_menus()`. The issue I'm currently having is figuring out how to add a class to the `#menu_item` if it has a parent menu item. My menu is setup like this:

- Main Item
- Main Item

  - Sub Item
  - Sub Item
- Main Item

I know from a code standpoint I need to check if the `$menu_item` has a child. From looking at the WordPress docs I see there is a function named `$has_children`. But I do not know the exactly syntax. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

in my **functions.php**

```
// custom menu example @ https://digwp.com/2011/11/html-formatting-custom-menus/
function clean_custom_menus() {
    $menu_name = 'primary'; // specify custom menu slug
    if (($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations[$menu_name])) {
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations[$menu_name]);
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

        $menu_list = '<nav role="navigation">' ."\n";
        $menu_list = '<div class="nav-wrapper">' . "\n";
        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t". '<ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">' ."\n";
        foreach ((array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item) {
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $url = $menu_item->url;

            //I would like to add a class to the li if it has a parent

            $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t\t". '<li><a href="'. $url .'">'. $title .'</a></li>' ."\n";
        }



        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t". '</ul>' ."\n";
        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t". '</div>' ."\n";
        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t". '</nav>' ."\n";
    } else {
        // $menu_list = '<!-- no list defined -->';
    }
    echo $menu_list;
}
```

**EDITED**

Here is my updated **functions.php**

```
// custom menu example @ https://digwp.com/2011/11/html-formatting-custom-menus/
function clean_custom_menus() {
    $menu_name = 'primary'; // specify custom menu slug
    if (($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations[$menu_name])) {
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations[$menu_name]);
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
        $menu_list = '<div class="nav-wrapper">' . "\n";
        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t". '<ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">' ."\n";
        foreach ((array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item) {
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $url = $menu_item->url;

            if ( $menu_item->post_parent != 0 ) {
                $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t\t". '<li class="dropdown"><a href="'. $url .'">'. $title .'</a></li>' ."\n";
            }
            else {
                $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t\t". '<li><a href="'. $url .'">'. $title .'</a></li>' ."\n";
            }
        }
        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t". '</ul>' ."\n";
        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t". '</div>' ."\n";
    } else {
        // $menu_list = '<!-- no list defined -->';
    }
    echo $menu_list;
```

My question is how do I change the logic, within the if statement (`if ( $menu_item->post_parent != 0 )`), so it will put the submenu in an `<ul>`?

This is how the current markup is like:

```
<ul>
 <li>Menu</li>
 <li class="dropdown">Sub Item</li>
 <li class="dropdown">Sub Item</li>
 <li class="dropdown">Sub Item</li>
 <li>Menu</li>
 ...
</ul>
```

This is how I would like the markup to be:

```
<ul>
 <li>Menu</li>
 <li>
    <a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Dropdown<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
    <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
     <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
     <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
     <li class="divider"></li>
     <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I think the logic would be either a while loop or another foreach loop within the if statement.

Comment: @vagelis Here is a codepen version of my navbar. https://codepen.io/herrjosuab/pen/gxGxYQ

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```
if ( $menu_item->post_parent != 0 ) {
    // yout post has a parent
}
```

Comment: @Herr Josua this can be done with JS also. If you can provide the markup I could help you with that

Comment: @vagelis Here is the markup <nav role="navigation">
                                <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
     <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Vision &amp; Purpose</a></li>
    
     <li><a href="#/what-we-do/">What we do</a></li>...

Comment: @VA79 If I need to create some additional markup for the submenu I assume I would need some while loop?

Comment: @HerrJosua please use a jsfiddle for the markup or something similar. The comment has cut out the rest